# Scala get all elements in a list less than a certain value

Tags: list, scala

I'm trying to get a partition of a list based on the values less than some parameter I'm passing into the function. I'm thinking of using the map function somehow to apply a function in order to make this new list, but I don't see how to do so:

```
exampleList.map(s => s<10)
```

For instance here, I want to get all the elements of the list that are less than 10, but I feel like this would just return a list of booleans. I know I can also use for comprehension with yield or maybe reduce, but I'm unsure of how to do so. (My Scala knowledge is limited)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `filter` method:

```
exampleList.filter(s => s < 10)
```

Using lambda syntactic sugar:

```
exampleList.filter(_ < 10)
```

Using list comprehensions

```
for (s <- exampleList; if s < 10) yield s
```

The `Seq` API is a good place to start if you want to expand your knowledge of the collection API:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq

Comment: Thank you very much for the different ways of implementing this solution!

Comment: The only issue is that now the scala compiler is complaining about a missing paramter type for s. How can I resolve this? I've tried doing
    for( s <- exampleList) {